# Does any language add additional speech marks to the question and exclamation mark in writing?

Tags: written-language, punctuation

In English (and any other languages I've studied) we have special marks which are used to identify questions (i.e. ?) and exclamations (i.e. !).

Does any written language add additional markers to cover additional types of expression - for instance having a 'request' marker, or an uncertainty marker.

I am aware that Spanish uses the inverted marks (¿ and ¡) to introduce the question, and there have been attempts to introduce the 'interrobang' (‽) for situations where one may want a questions to be asked in a excited manner, but those feel more like extensions of the current marks, and nothing new.

Comment: I hope this lies within those areas that this site is happy to answer.

Comment: So you're looking for a language that already uses the ? and !, plus additional ones?

Comment: @Draconis I've rephrased the first paragraph. The language need not literally use the symbols ? and !, the important thing is that it adds a marker for a different type of sentence.

Comment: The Ge’ez script used for languages like Amharic and Trigrinya has [a number of additional punctuation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geʽez_script#Punctuation), like ‘section mark’, ‘paragraph mark’ and ‘preface colon’. Additional [Chinese punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_punctuation#Punctuation_marks) include an enumeration comma 、 (used for lists), a middle dot · (to separate names from other languages), 《title marks》 (for, well, titles) and, rarer, [proper name marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_name_mark). I’m sure there’s lots more.

Comment: The Javanese script uses several punctuation marks called [_pepadan_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script#Pepadan) used in poetic texts for different purposes, such as marking the beginning and the end of a poem, as separators between stanzas, as a mark to show the change from one poetic meter to another, etc. Also, the Javanese script uses a special marks to enclose titles, and in epistolary usage there are marks which are put at the beginning of the letter to indicate whether the writer's social status is higher, lower, or equal to that of the addressee.

Comment: [Armenian punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_alphabet#Punctuation) are quiet interesting. Some marks, including the question mark and the exclamation mark, are placed above the vowel whose tone is modified.